# How to extract DEM (Digital Elevation Model) from 3D model

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, sketchup

How can I extract a Digital Elevation Model from a 3D model of a building, made with SketchUp, using Blender,qgis or any other software?

Comment: Can sketchup write any of these with z as attribute or coordinate? http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html. If so then this should help: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Export your terrain object from SketchUp as a .dae file (or .kmz if you're using the free version - rename the .kmz extension to .zip and extract it find the .dae file inside)

Open the .dae mesh in [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net) (free) and export mesh to .xyz points format, ignoring normals. Now, you can add the .xyz as a layer in QGIS using 'add delimited text layer'. Specify your x and y column, 'space' as custom delimiter, and that you have no header row. Looking at the data table, column 3 will contain your Z values.

Remember that unless your model was already georefenced, you will probably need to translate, rotate and scale the resulting layer, as required.

You can now use the raster > interpolation module to create a raster based DEM.

Answer (score 1):

A second solution, which seems more efficient to me, after hours trying to achieve something with the same initial purpose (extraction of a DEM from a mesh constructed with Sketchup [in order to use visibility analysis tools].

1. If possible, export the Sketchup object as a *.obj file, as it seems that it is the only format that keeps the scale and orientation of the model
2. Open it with [CloudCompare](https://cloudcompare.org/) (opensource and free) and select it. If needed, georeference it [Ctrl + T / Edit > Apply transformation > "From > to axes", give the true coordinates of your origin point in Sketchup]
3. Add sample points on the surface of your mesh [Edit>Mesh>Sample points]. As for the number of points, 1.000.000 per a 300 m² building with walls 3 m high give good results.
4. Select your sampled cloud. Rasterize it [Tools > Projection > Rasterize]. Important parameters:

- Projection direction: Z
- Empty cells. Fill with **kriging**

Update grid to see the result, click on Raster in order to save the file.